# Efficiency of putting a query in the C# foreach condition

Tags: c#, .net, performance

I came across this c# code in a project today and I couldn't help but question its efficiency:

```
SPList spList = spWeb.GetListCustom("tasks");
foreach (SPListITem item in spList.GetItems(query))
{
    //... do something with the SPListCollection it returned
}
```

Being from a Java background, the spList.GetItems(query) definitely made me think that its a performance hit.  I would've done something like the following to improve it:

```
SPList spList = spWeb.GetListCustom("tasks");
SPListIteCollection taskListCollection = taskList.GetItems(query);
foreach (SPListITem item in taskListCollection)
{
    //... do something with the SPListCollection it returned
}
```

However, the code is in C#...

So my question is: would the code I suggested above improve performance, or have I missed something fundamental about C#'s foreach loop?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see why this would have bad performance characteristics in either Java or .Net; under normal circumstances, GetItems would be evaluated before your list would be enumerated, and GetItems presumably returns IEnumerable<T> or IEnumerable. Your VM would have to be really confused to turn this into multiple queries. Perhaps you're confusing this with a classic for loop, which evaluates the check condition on each iteration?

Comment: I knew there is something special about foreach. Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The two blocks of code are completely identical, and will compile to the exact same IL in Release mode.

Unlike a regular `for` loop, a `foreach` loop will only use the collection once (to call `GetEnumerator`).  Therefore, you have nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

Second code block is just clearer to read, not other benefits. I could understand better that the foreach is playing with  `SPListIteCollection`.

Answer (score 0):

the enumerator in the foreach is only evaluated once, works the same in java too.